# Install packages via Bower

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, bower

I'm new to front-end technologies, but I need to install a package via Bower.
Here is the package: https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record

The thing is that after I installed all dependencies, I obtain a folder with 219.9 MB of dependencies and so on. All this folders are situated in `/public/videojs-record` directory of my Laravel project. So, I can connect all `.css` and `.js` files like in documentation of package.
These files are 4 times bigger than my entire project and they are situated in the public folder, that has to slow down my website, yep? 
How can I move that dependencies out of the public folder, for example in `/vendor` directory of my project, and connect this `.css` and `.js` files in my HTML?

Comment: First, why Bower? This package supports NPM, too. Second, those files aren't going to slow down your website - they're mostly for development use, and probably include things like test suites, sample videos, etc. Third, this is typically handled by using something like Webpack to take only what's necessary and package it into a "build" that you'd use publicly.

Comment: So, now they are in my /public/videojs-record directory, and in HTML I connect them like
        <script src="/videojs-record/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="/videojs-record/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
        <script src="/videojs-record/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

Can I somehow move all this folders at other directory, not public? If yes, how can I indicate the correct path to this files after moving them out from public folder?

Comment: @ceejayoz Bower, because I found it better, it solves only the front-end dependencies and download exactly what it needs (from different comparing posts and questions on stackoverflow and documentation)

Comment: In all that research you didn't discover that [even Bower doesn't recommend Bower these days](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/)? "As you might have noticed, we started recommending Yarn as an alternative to Bower for new front-end projects."

Comment: But if forget about it and give a answer to my question, can I move these folders out from public folder, and if yes - how can I reference them in html?

Comment: Again, the modern, typical way of handling this is using something like Webpack to compile a production-ready minified version of just what's needed for the front-end.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Laravel's docs also recommend/default to using NPM for frontend dependencies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/frontend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, there is no need to use Bower. Just use NPM as mentioned in the doc of said package.

Laravel comes already with a package.json and a webpack configuration. The normal way to add frontend dependencies is:

1. Install all Laravel basic fe dependencies

   `$ npm install`
2. Install a external package

   `$ npm install videojs-record`
3. Built the packages for development

   `$ npm run dev`

   Running a watcher

   `$ npm run watch`

   Built the packages for production

   `$ npm run prod`

The dependencies will be stored in `node_modules`. This folder can get very huge but you don't commit it to GIT or push it to the server manually.